# For bivariate linear model, if the residuals ARE normal, but the data is NOT normal, can I make inferences about the slope coefficient?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, regression-coefficients, standard-error

For convenience and context, I'm looking at the formula for standard error of the slope coefficient from here: https://www.statology.org/standard-error-of-regression-slope/

[image]

If X is not normally distributed but the residuals are, is the estimated slope coefficient's distribution characterized by the T-distribution?

Comment: Residuals are *never* independently Normally distributed, so you likely are trying to ask about the *errors* in the model.

Comment: @whuber, yes your comment makes sense.

Comment: In Kutner's Applied Linear Statistical Models Ch2 Page 42, it explains that the sampling distribution of $b_1$ is normal because $b_1$ is a linear combination of $Y_i$ and if we assume $Y_i$ is normally distributed, then a linear combination of $Y_i$ is also normally distributed.  I _think_ this is the answer I was looking for, if I'm not misunderstanding the passage.  Would love feedback on this..

Comment: It contradicts what you write.  Because the estimated slope is Normal, it is *not* characterized by a Student t distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The usual linear regression model does not assume that X is normal. The assumptions are independence, homoscedasticity, linearity and normality *of residuals*.

Comment: Your comment about residuals is not quite correct, as my linked answer discusses.

Comment: The model makes no assumptions whatsoever about residuals: you seem to use "residual" (observed difference between response and fitted value) instead of "error" (a random variable in the model).